# Admin page content not loading: latter doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, admin, layout, error, containers

I'm running Magento 2.1.3, and am seeing empty page content in my custom module's admin page, with the error `Broken reference: the '[layout element name]' element cannot be added as child to 'left', because the latter doesn't exist` - I've tried the permission fix in [Magento 2.0: main.CRITICAL: Broken reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108113/magento-2-0-main-critical-broken-reference), but that's not working either. The layout xml is not complicated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceContainer name="left">
    <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Section\Edit\Tabs"
        name="namespace_module_block_section_edit_tabs" />
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Section\Edit" name="namespace_module_block_edit" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Any ideas as to why this would be throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: There was another custom module updating the layout, and removing the 'admin-2columns-left' layout setting.